# grafana GUI issues with "context deadline exceeded" error

Tags: devops, monitoring, redhat, grafana

I have installed grafana locally in a heavily closed networked node. As it didnt have any outbound network provision, I had to install grafana and all of it's dependencies manually there. Now after successful installation when it try to access it I am getting this in its GUI:
[image]

There is no reverse proxy set in the server and i have tried our #2 also, didn't help.
In the error logs i see logs like

```
eror msg="Failed to send usage stats" logger=metrics err="Post \"https://stats.grafana.org/grafana-usage-report\": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeou
t exceeded while awaiting headers)"
```

the entire logs are provided here:
[image]

I had installed the same binaries and dependencies on a relatively open networked server and there it is working fine
Is this any issue related to it's sqlite db or am I missing something out?

Your suggestions will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Could you change this config in the grafana.ini file to

```
reporting_enabled = false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).